# JavaFX - convert Group of images to Image

Tags: java, javafx

I had to convert a text to an image, which I managed to do with .awt it is a bit monstrous but it might do for now, if you have a solution to convert a text to a image (in javafx) with alpha background and to adjust the size of the image automatically to the text length is also very much appreciated.

My actual question: I have two images, one from converting a text to an image and the other a character, what I need is to convert/merge both images into one and the text to be in the middle of the character's image (to front).

What I've done so far:

```
 private Image textToImage(String text) {
    Label label = new Label(text);

    // label.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    label.setStyle("-fx-fill: brown; -fx-font-size: 1.5em");
    label.setWrapText(true);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(label));
    WritableImage img = new WritableImage(70, 70);
    scene.snapshot(img);
    return img;
}

public Group test() {

    // The character
    ImageView img2 = new ImageView(secondImg());
    img2.setBlendMode(BlendMode.MULTIPLY);

    // The text
    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(textToImage("word"));
    img1.setLayoutX(img2.getImage().getWidth() / 2);
    img1.setLayoutY(img2.getImage().getHeight() / 2);

    Group g = new Group(img1, img2);
    g.setLayoutX(100);
    g.setLayoutY(100);

    return g;
}
```

I get this: [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtmJW.png)

Now I would like to convert somehow back the Group of images to a singe Image. Why? Because the character object I am using in the constructor:

```
this.setImage(--the two merged images--)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution that comes to my mind is to just render all your content into a Canvas or into a Scene and then take a snapshot of them.

Comment: Could you provide an example or some links? Thanks.

Comment: Links? There's always the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-)